# Why can't I get 960.gs to work properly with Meteor?

Tags: html, css, meteor, 960.gs

I have a problem with getting the CSS framwork [960.gs](http://960.gs/) to work with [Meteor](http://meteor.com). I've put the reset.css in a *lib/* folder so it loads first. After that, *960.css* and *960_12_col.css* is loaded from the *css/* folder. However, when I copy the example (only the things from inside of body-tags) from http://960.gs/demo_24_col.html into my Meteor application, it simply doesn't work. I don't expect colors and other styling to follow but the grid system should be working. I've checked so everything is loaded in the right order but can't find any more way to finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a silly mistake. The demo uses the 24 column grid. I've used the 12 column grid file. Once I used the 24 column, everything was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound sad, but have you tried loading all the css as they do that demo page? Ordering from top down in your html is the way to load css with notions of specificity.

Comment: I'm using the framework Meteor where I put files in different folder to have them loaded in different orders. I haven't loaded the *css/demo.css* from the demo since that almost only contains colors and such. I want the grid system. However, upon checking the demos source once again, I saw that the demo used the 24 column grid instead of 12 columns, which were the files I'm using. Thanks for helping out!